# Resources of minimized programs in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, cpu-usage, memory-management

When a program is minimized to the taskbar in Linux does it use less resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually not.

If the window requires a lot of resources to render (e.g. games, Video Player, etc) it *may* be that the minimized application detects that it's minimized and stops doing the resource intensive tasks.

But that's usually not the case. So the answer should be *NO*.

Answer (score 2):

No. Its windows are not being displayed, but they still exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in some cases if the window drawing is expensive, e.g. a lot is changing.